# Media Element and Progress Bar Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, mediaelement

I would like to play sounds, and display a progress bar below each sounds
I'm displaying the current progress thanks to this in my VM: (source: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/playing-media-content-windows)

```
player.CurrentStateChanged += player_CurrentStateChanged;
[...]
 void player_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediaPlayer = sender as MediaElement;
        if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
        {
            var duration = mediaPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
            ThreadingHelper.ExecuteAsyncAction(() =>
                {
                    do
                    {
                        ThreadingHelper.ExecuteOnUiThread(() =>
                        {
                            Progress = mediaPlayer.Position.TotalSeconds * 100 / duration;
                        });
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                    } while (IsPlaying);
                });
        }
    }
```

and xaml:

```
<!--TITLE-->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sound.Libelle}"
                           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

            <ProgressBar Height="20" Width="400" Value="{Binding Progress}"></ProgressBar>
```

The progress bar display correctly, problem is when I play a second sound, the first progress bar is also updated, due to binding with my Progress property.

I don't know how to prevent this behavior, any ideas are welcome.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this behavior occurs only when I'm starting another sound while a first is playing. My first sound stop, the second start but both progress bar are updated

EDIT2: A little more code:

```
 private void PlaySong()
    {
        MediaElement player = null; // get the media element from App resources
        if (Application.Current.Resources.Contains("MediaPlayer"))
        {
            player = Application.Current.Resources["MediaPlayer"] as MediaElement;
        }
        if (player != null)
        {
            if (IsPlaying)
            {
                player.Stop();
                player.MediaEnded -= player_MediaEnded;
                player.CurrentStateChanged -= player_CurrentStateChanged;
            }
            else
            {
                player.Source = new Uri(Sound.Link, UriKind.Relative);
                player.Play();
                player.MediaEnded += (o, args) => player_MediaEnded(player, args);
                player.CurrentStateChanged += player_CurrentStateChanged;
                IsPlaying = true;
            }
        }            
    }
```

This is my `PlaySong()` method called `onClick`, who gets the unique `MediaPlayer` defined in my app.xaml. It play or stop according to current sound state.

This is my xaml, it's a template for a `<ListBox>` control bound to an ObservableCollection of SoundViewModel

```
<Button x:Name="SoundButton"
                Command="{Binding PlaySongCommand}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Style="{StaticResource EmptyButtonStyle}">
            <StackPanel Margin="12,0,0,12">

                <!--TITLE-->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sound.Libelle}"
                           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

            <ProgressBar Height="20" Width="400" Value="{Binding Progress}"></ProgressBar>
        </StackPanel>
        <!-- LONG HOLD GESTION-->
        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="AllsoundMenu" IsZoomEnabled="True">
                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Add to favorite" 
                                      Command="{Binding AddToFavoriteCommand}" />
                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Add as a ringtone" Command="{Binding AddToRingtoneCommand}" />
            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
```

So one ProgressBar/Sound and only one `MediaElement` in the app.
Hope this helps you to see clearer.

Maybe I souldn't have only one `MediaElement`, but it seemed right to implement this way.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your setup. Does you each player have it's own ProgressBar?  If so, are do each Player/ProgressBar combo have its own viewmodel?  If no to either of these questions, that would explain why you see the behavior you do.

Comment: OKay. Hmm actually I have only one Player, and multiple ProgressBar, maybe I should try to set up Player/ProgressBar combo ?

Comment: So just to make sure I'm understanding, how do you visually distinguish between your different ProgressBars and what they are associated too?  Are they in a ItemsControl of some sort?  Perhaps if you showed us more of your XAML, what you are trying to accomplish would be more clear...

Comment: Ok, I've added more code, hope this will help to understand what I tried to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try to remove the handler from the 'player' object when the sound is not running. i hope it will help. like this:

```
 void player_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediaPlayer = sender as MediaElement;
        if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
        {
            var duration = mediaPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
            ThreadingHelper.ExecuteAsyncAction(() =>
                {
                    do
                    {
                        ThreadingHelper.ExecuteOnUiThread(() =>
                        {
                            //A list of values ， nowPlay means that the sound you are playing
                            ProgressList[nowPlay] = mediaPlayer.Position.TotalSeconds * 100 / duration;
                        });
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                    } while (IsPlaying);
                });

        }
    }
```

xaml:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ProgressList}" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                        <ProgressBar Height="20" Width="400" Value="{Binding Values}"/>
                  </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class Progress : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        int _values;
        public int Values
        {
            get
            {
                return _values;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _values)
                {
                    _values = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Values");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

 public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        List<Progress> _progress = new List<Progress>();
        int _values = 100;
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
            _progress.Add(new Progress());
            _progress.Add(new Progress());
            _progress[0].Values = 50;
            _progress[1].Values = 100;

        }
     ...
     }
```

Comment: Thanks. nothing change :/, I also tried to remove the handler when the stopped event is called

Comment: @Pierpowl : i known that, if you want those two ProgressBars show different values, you couldn't bind them to the same property (Progress). try to declare a list for those ProgressBars to bind.

Comment: okay, could you explain little more, you mean to have a liste of property to bind?

Comment: yes, bind a list of property to the ListBox, and change your 'player_CurrentStateChanged' function, you need know which song you are playing, and then change its ProgressBars's value.